# Cross references in type parameters

Tags: kotlin

For example in Java I could write:

```
public abstract class Element<S extends Snapshot> { ... }
public abstract class Snapshot<E extends Element> { ... }
```

And then, somewhere, extend this classes:

```
public class SnapshotImpl extends Snapshot<ElementImpl> { ... }
public class ElementImpl extends Element<SnapshotImpl> { ... }
```

But when I tried to implement same class hierarchy in Kotlin:

```
abstract class Element<S : Snapshot> 
abstract class Snapshot<E : Element>
```

I got following compilation errors:

`Error:(6, 28) Kotlin: One type argument expected for class Snapshot<E> defined in model
 Error:(6, 25) Kotlin: One type argument expected for class Element<S> defined in model`

Is there any way to reproduce same type parameter restrictions in Kotlin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't have raw types, you cannot just drop the type parameters.

One option similar to raw types is to use [star projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections):

```
abstract class Element<S : Snapshot<*>> { /* ... */ }
abstract class Snapshot<E : Element<*>> { /* ... */ }
```

But you won't be able to normally work with the type parameters generic members.

---

Another option is to introduce mutual constraints like this:

```
abstract class Element<E : Element<E, S>, S : Snapshot<S, E>>() { /* ... */ }
abstract class Snapshot<S : Snapshot<S, E>, E : Element<E, S>>() { /* ... */ }
```

With this definition, you can be sure that if you define `SomeSnapshot: Snapshot<SomeSnapshot, SomeElement>`, the type `SomeElement` *is aware of* `SomeSnapshot`, because it is constrained to be derived from `Element<SomeElement, SomeSnapshot>`.

Then the implementation would be:

```
class SomeElement : Element<SomeElement, SomeSnapshot>() { /* ... */ }
class SomeSnapshot : Snapshot<SomeSnapshot, SomeElement>() { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this issue when designing one of the abstract layers of my app. 
First of the options in [hotkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43786246/5043494) fails to compile with "This type parameter violates the Finite Bound Restriction" (at least with newer Kotlin 1.2.71). The second one works, but can be optimized a bit. Even thought it is still bloated it makes a difference, especially when you have more type parameters. Here is the code:

```
abstract class Element<S : Snapshot<*, *>> { /* ... */ }
abstract class Snapshot<E : Element<S>, S : Snapshot<E, S>> { /* ... */ }
```