# How to cross-reference types in parameters

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to cross-reference types in their generic parameters.
In java, I have this:

```
public interface Group<C extends Child> {
  List<C> getChildren();
}

public interface Child<G extends Group> {
  G getParent();
}

class MyGroup implements Group<MyChild> {
  @Override
  public List<MyChild> getChildren() {
    return null;
  }
}

class MyChild implements Child<MyGroup> {
  @Override
  public MyGroup getParent() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Using AndroidStudio's "Convert to Kotlin" function results in:

```
interface Group<C : Child<*>> {
  val children: List<C>
}

interface Child<G : Group<*>> {
  val parent: G
}

internal inner class MyGroup : Group<MyChild> {
  override val children: List<MyChild>?
    get() = null
}

internal inner class MyChild : Child<MyGroup> {
  override val parent: MyGroup?
    get() = null
}
```

Which throws: Finite Bound Restriction violated.

Is there any way I can write such code in kotlin?

Comment: Bro does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786012/cross-references-in-type-parameters?

Comment: @zsmb13 mybe it is duplicated. but the answer is not the perfect way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like that way. because it will introduce another generic parameter. instead you can introduce a middle role `Node` interface to describe the relationship, for example:

```
interface Node<out T>;

interface Group<out C : Node<*>> : Node<C> {
    val children: List<C>
}

interface Child<out G : Group<*>> : Node<G> {
    val parent: G;
}

class MyGroup : Group<MyChild> {
    override val children: List<MyChild>
        get() = TODO("not implemented")
}

class MyChild : Child<MyGroup> {
    override val parent: MyGroup
        get() = TODO("not implemented")
}
```

the middle role just like as `kotlin.Function`:

```
public interface Function<out R>
```

*Note*: the `out` variance is optional.

Comment: Great solution! If you write this answer on the duplicated question I can upvote it there and remove this question.

Comment: @Simas sir, thank you for admit my answer. but I'm not good at English, I don't like to repeat it. let it live just here. :)